# Magento base_url reset every time I reboot the EC2 instance

Tags: magento, amazon-ec2, bitnami

Looks like there is a script running every time I reboot the Magento EC2 instance. How do I stop the script or change it to something else?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this script updates the IP address. The tool is called "updateip" and it is in "/opt/bitnami" folder. You can use it to set your hostname or you can simply rename it to avoid to change your IP address.
and [more](https://wiki.bitnami.com/Virtual_Appliances_Quick_Start_Guide#How_to_configure_the_application_IP.2fhostname.3f).